# Why doesn't my MKPointAnnotation appear when the view loads?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, coordinates, cgpoint

In my app, the user saves some data, including a map coordinate. In my code, a pin is dropped at the saved map coordinate. Here is my code-

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mapView.delegate = self

    // Data loading
    itemNameTextField.delegate = self
    itemDescriptionLabel.delegate = self
    itemLocationTextView.delegate = self

    // Press recognizer

    if let item = item {

        itemNameTextField.text = item.itemName
        itemDescriptionLabel.text = item.itemDescription
        itemLocationTextView.text = item.itemPlace

        let dropPin = MKPointAnnotation()
        dropPin.coordinate = mapView.convert(item.mapPoint, toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        dropPin.title = "Location of \(item.itemName)"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(dropPin)
        print("Set the location of item pin to \(String(describing: dropPin.coordinate))")

    }

    // Styles
    itemInfoView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor(red:0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7
    itemInfoView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45

    itemLocationView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor(red:0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.75)
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowRadius = 1.7
    itemLocationView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.45

    locationAdressTextview.layer.cornerRadius = 2
    locationAdressTextview.layer.shadowColor =  UIColor(red:0/255.0, green:0/255.0, blue:0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    locationAdressTextview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.50)
    locationAdressTextview.layer.shadowRadius = 1.6
    locationAdressTextview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
}
```

I know that the app *does* save the pin coordinates as a `CGPoint`, and I know that it converts it from a `CGPoint` to a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, because of the `print` statements I placed. However, when the screen loads, the print statement shows a valid coordinate, but there is no pin on the map, and I get no errors. Can somebody please help me? Thanks!

Comment: If you need clarification, or you need me to add more code, just comment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever the map should display an annotation the `MKMapViewDelegate` method `viewForAnnotation` is called so you have to implement that method and return a view according to your needs

Sample code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myAnnotationView")
    // configure the view

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am relatively new to swift. What does `PinAnnonationView` refer to?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I have updated my answer. You can subclass `MKAnnotationView` to add your needs.

Comment: What changes would you make to the rest of the code?

Comment: Implement that delegate method so the map displays a simple view for each annotation at first. If that works, configure the view as you want it to be. My code sample above should get you started.